# Best Approach to storing chat history?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, mongodb, database-recommendation

I'm building a chat application (Yes, another one :P) and am really curious about the best way to store a chat's history(String username, String Message, Time, and possibly string channel depending on how I end up setting it up.

Since I'm using PostgreSQL anyway, I was tempted for going with it for chat history. However, I don't see a sane approach for using it to do this without generating a new row for every message, something obviously not very scale-able.

I know some MongoDB and was thinking that using a json array for each channel and storing the history in that would work well.

Is using two entirely databases in the same application a terrible idea?

Are there any other alternatives I should take a look at? (I'm open to pretty much anything)

Is there a popular PostgreSQL way of doing this? I took a look at a [JSON columns](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-json.html), but it seemed fairly new and limited at the moment.

Comment: *"However, I don't see a sane approach for using it to do this without generating a new row for every message, something obviously not very scale-able"* . Why not? So long as you use a commit delay or async commit, and/or batch messages into transactions, you should be fine.

Comment: Adding to @CraigRinger's comment, I am wondering if constantly updating the MongoDB document for a given chat is faster than storing rows in PostgreSQL (or fast enough for being a viable solution).

Comment: I'll add a warning - having an unbounded array is a very bad design approach for MongoDB - it causes the document to constantly grow (has a limit of 16MB) and can cause problems.  It would be a better idea to have documents per message and collections for each channel, but likely testing would be needed to see how well/badly it would work.  Hard to speak to best practice with such a general description.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I was concerned that the number of rows per table would get out of hand, as it would be easy for even a lightly used chat service to generate thousands of messages daily. It seems like I would run into the same problems using mongodb as well though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [*hstore*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/hstore.html) for use [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model). *hstore* is available from pgsql 8.4. If you have installed *json* you can then use function **hstore_to_json(hstore)**

```
select hstore_to_json('"a key"=>1, b=>t, c=>null, d=>12345, e=>012345, f=>1.234, g=>2.345e+4')
```

this will output:

```
{"a key": "1", "b": "t", "c": null, "d": "12345", "e": "012345", "f": "1.234", "g": "2.345e+4"}
```